# What to do if NSString has " inside link

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

This might be a stupid question, but what do I do when an NSString has a " inside it? It is being read as if the end of the text has come.
For example:

```
 NSString *url1 = @"<a href="http://maps.apple.com/?q=cupertino">Cupertino</a>"
```

Please help.
All help is appreciated.

Comment: Xcode doesn't read anything.  Compilers read string literals, and you must know how to "escape" quotes and other special characters in such string literals.

Answer (score 5):

You should escape it with `\"`:

```
NSString *s = @"\"This string contains quotes.\""
```

Answer (score 1):

The character \ will be ignored. So try this -

```
NSString *url1 = @"<a href=\"http://maps.apple.com/?q=cupertino\">Cupertino</a>"
```